# How do I make my visualforce page rerender?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

I'm using visualforce & apex classes to build a page where i'm outputting records from custom object. On the visualforce page I have a date field that on submission, will update the outputted records based on the date entered. I'm having a problem where the results are not updated and i'm not sure why. I would appreciate help with identifying what i'm doing wrong or suggested steps to debug this. Thanks!

Here is my apex class

```
public class bookingScheduleController {
    public date myDate { get; set; }
    public list<Vessel__c> vessel = new List<Vessel__c>();   

    public list<Vessel__c> GetVessels() {
        myDate = system.today();
        doSearch();
        return vessel;
    }

    public PageReference searchDate() {
        doSearch();
        return null;
    }

    public void doSearch() {
        vessel = [Select Id,Name from Vessel__c WHERE DateTmp__c > :mydate AND Status__c ='Current' ORDER BY Name];
    }

}
```

And my Visualforce

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="bookingScheduleController">
<apex:stylesheet value="{! $Resource.bookingSchedule }"/>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:input type="date" value="{!myDate}" />   
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchDate}" rerender="scheduler" >
        <apex:param value="{!myDate}" assignTo="{!myDate}"/>
        </apex:commandButton>
    </apex:form>

  <div class="scheduler" >
  <apex:repeat var="vessel" value="{!Vessels}">
        /* Vessel information */
  </apex:repeat>
  </div>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to build a search page? If that's all you're doing, remove the apex:param line and change your scheduler div to an apex:outputPanel. As far as I know, Visualforce rerender works on apex:outputpanel, and not on div tags. And you need an Id, not a class, to tell it what to rerender:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="bookingScheduleController">
<apex:stylesheet value="{! $Resource.bookingSchedule }"/>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:input type="date" value="{!myDate}" />   
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchDate}" rerender="schedulerOP" />
    </apex:form>

  <apex:outputPanel class="scheduler" id="schedulerOP">
  <apex:repeat var="vessel" value="{!Vessels}">
        /* Vessel information */
  </apex:repeat>
  </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```